# Функции в php

Tags: php

Можно ли установить какую нибудь кнопочку прямо на этой странице,чтобы включить функцию , но так чтобы она при обновлении не срабатывала?

<?php
session_start();

```
function add_basket($id){
    mysql_connect("localhost","name user","password") ;
        mysql_select_db("name DB");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog  WHERE id = '$id'  ") ;
          $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);               
                     $_SESSION['id']   = $row["id"];
                       $id =    $_SESSION['id']; 
         $result = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO basket(goodsid) VALUES($id)");
                return $result;
               }
```

//add_basket(4);

?>

Comment: Ajax......

Answer (score 1):

Можно но, только используя js. На php никак

Comment: Обычно php и js ортогональны: на php пишется серверная часть, а на js клиентская. Вы хотели сказать "можно, но только на стороне клиента"?